# crashing in custom camera App -Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

i used Custom camera app but not open the camera fragment and application crashes.my code in below what wrong me in my code? please help me!!!

TakeCameraFragment:::

```
public class TakeCameraFragment extends Fragment {
     Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;

    protected static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 0;
    static String FilePAth = "";
    Button takePicture;
    static String base64string = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camerafragment,
                container, false);

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        Log.v("log_tag", "mCamera :: "+mCamera);


        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_fragment);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        takePicture = (Button) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicturefragment);
        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureframent);

            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }

    public boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {

        try {
            Log.v("log_tag", "camera try:::"+mCamera);
             mCamera.open();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
            Log.v("log_tag", "camera catch:::"+mCamera);
            releaseCamera();
        }
        return mCamera;
    }



    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraAppFragment");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());

        FilePAth = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_fragment_"
                + timeStamp + ".jpg";

        Log.v("log", " FilePAth " + FilePAth);

        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_fragment_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    PictureCallback mPictureframent = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                /*
                 * Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                 * returnIntent.putExtra("data", data); setResult(RESULT_OK,
                 * returnIntent); finish();
                 */

                Log.v("log_tag", "data :: " + data);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                SetPictureImageFragment fm2 = new SetPictureImageFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relative_camerafragment_id, fm2,
                        "HELLO");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putByteArray("position", data);
                fm2.setArguments(bundle);

                //SetPictureImageFragment fm2 = new SetPictureImageFragment();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };


    /*
     * public void onBackPressed() { /*Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
     * returnIntent.putExtra("path", FilePAth); setResult(RESULT_OK,
     * returnIntent); finish(); };
     */

}
```

SetPictureImageFragment:::

```
public class SetPictureImageFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView img;
    Bundle bundle;
    byte[] path;
    Button btnTakecanclePicture;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capturepicturefragment, null);

        Log.v("log_tag","SetPictureImageFragment");
        bundle = this.getArguments();
        path = bundle.getByteArray("position");

        Log.v("log_tag","SetPictureImageFragment ::: Path :: "+path);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_fragment_imageview);
        btnTakecanclePicture=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnTakecanclePicture);
        //img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(path, 0,path.length);
        Log.v("log_tag","SetPictureImageFragment ::: bitmap :: "+b);

        img.setImageBitmap(b);
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    /*  btnTakecanclePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                TakeCameraFragment fm2 = new TakeCameraFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relative_cameraimageview_fragment, fm2,
                        "HELLO");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


                /*FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm
                  .beginTransaction();
                CreateStoreFragment fm2 = new CreateStoreFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relative_cameraimageview_fragment,
                  fm2, "HELLO");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        */

        return view;
    }
}
```

Camera preview Class::

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    // Constructor that obtains context and camera
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);

        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // left blank for now
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally left blank for a test
        }
    }
}
```

i Get Error:::

```
  03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at com.buymysari.camera.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:28)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:609)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:178)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:707)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1981)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1143)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4674)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-26 11:32:48.325: E/AndroidRuntime(28732):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check my answer and change your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mCamera` object is `null`..You need to change this line

```
Camera.open();
```

into

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
```

Change like this..

```
private Camera getCameraInstance() {

    try {
        Log.v("log_tag", "camera try:::"+mCamera);
          mCamera = Camera.open();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // cannot get camera or does not exist
        Log.v("log_tag", "camera catch:::"+mCamera);
        releaseCamera();
    }
    return mCamera;
}
```

Comment: thanks to reply... but i change mCamera = Camera.open(); but same error here.

Comment: what is 28th line in camerapreview class

Comment: @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
  try {
   mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
   mCamera.startPreview();
   //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // left blank for now
  }
 }

Comment: i change your code but it work .but i used in second time crashed app.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main ,java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-26 12:01:20.153: E/AndroidRuntime(3261):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)

Comment: @crickpatel0024 You are using image in camera so it takes lot of memory..you can check this for handling bitmaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object